# How to access the dbms_output buffer from C code?

Tags: c, oracle, plsql, oracle-call-interface, dbms-output

Various Oracle solutions involve PL/SQL snippets with the `dbms_output` package -- in particular the `dbms_output.put_line()`.

These work with the `sqlplus` interpreter, but some of our code uses the C API (`oci.h`, `ociapr.h` and friends).

Is there a way to get the contents of the DBMS buffer(s) with those functions?

Comment: Have you seen this oracle sample code? [Programmer's Guide to the Oracle7 Server Call Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/api/doc/OCI73/apa1.htm)

Comment: Oracle documentation for Oracle Call Interface for 12.2 is at https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnoci/oci-programming-basics.html#GUID-46090C93-4BC4-4E88-AA09-3E9B716917A3 -- tl;dr so not sure if you can invoke the procedures in `DBMS_OUTPUT` or not.  DBMS_OUTPUT doco: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_OUTPUT.html#GUID-C1400094-18D5-4F36-A2C9-D28B0E12FD8C

Comment: Yes, @ryyker, the sample code is, pretty much, the only available documentation for the API. Unfortunately, it makes no mention of `dbms_output`. I understand, that the procedures in the package operate on some buffer(s) internal to the server -- my question is, how can a client access them. `sqlplus` and various Oracle client GUI-clients all do it, but their sources aren't open... I can invoke an SQL-statement, but the only known way of obtaining a result is by processing a _data set_ (when the statement is a `select ...`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the procedure `DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINE` to retrieve information from the buffer. I can't help you with the C code, but the below code are the Oracle PL/SQL procedures to call.

Before you run the PL/SQL snippet that calls `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`, run this procedure to enable the buffer:

```
dbms_output.enable;
```

After you run the PL/SQL snippet, you can retrieve a single line of output like this:

```
declare
    v_line varchar2(32767);
    v_status integer;
begin
    dbms_output.get_line(v_line, v_status);

    --Do something with the output in V_LINE here
    ...
end;
/
```

For larger output, you may want to call [`DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINES`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_OUTPUT.html#GUID-E9459EA9-4498-4131-B858-64C04C79762E), which returns an array of strings and the number of lines. See the package documentation for a full description of the procedures and arguments.

Comment: Using `dbms_output` from `sqlplus` is easy -- and examples abound. Doing it from C-code is, what I'm looking for here.

Comment: Sorry I can't help with the C part. But the code I provided is all PL/SQL, and nothing specific to sqlplus. However you call your current PL/SQL snippet, you can simply add those commands before and after it.

Comment: Looks like there is no one left out there, who accesses Oracle from C (or even C++) programs. There are still C-experts and SQL-experts, but no one with _both_... Certainly not on SO...

Comment: @MikhailT. There are some users here with both of those skill sets, but not many. I added a more specific tag, and hopefully that will attract them to this question.

Comment: Check this (mine project) https://github.com/tora-tool/tora/blob/master/src/widgets/tooutput.cpp Basically you need to call DBMS_OUTPUT: ENABLE GET_LINES GET_LINE